# How to prevent DOM children from inherit addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, dom, inheritance, addeventlistener

I need a custom context menu, so I use `addEventListener` for it, but I wish to have it on the div1, but not on div2, how I can do it **without** to add the same listener with `stopPropagation()`

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1" style="background-color:green;border:3px solid black;width:300px;height:300px;margin:auto;">
<div id="div2" style="background-color:yellow;border:3px solid black;width:100px;height:100px;margin:auto;margin-top:-50px;">
some text
</div>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById('div1').addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e)
    {
    console.log('contextmenu');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if (e.target === this) console.log...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check the event target in the handler, and abort if the target was `<div2>`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `false` as a third parameter of addEventListener

```
document.getElementById('div1').addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e)
{
    console.log('contextmenu');
}, false);
```

Or
`if(e.currentTarget.getAttribute("id") != "div1") e.preventDefault();`